# VuePress build deletes CNAME file in ./docs needed for Github Pages custom domain

Tags: github-pages, vuepress

I'm trying to get VuePress to work well with GitHub Pages and a custom domain. I have the site working -- https://www.southertonrr.com [(repo)](https://github.com/Bradley-Southerton/southertonrr.com) -- as long as I manually add a CNAME file to my output folder ('./dest', or in my case, './docs', because that's where GitHub Pages looks for the site) every time after I issue a build command. Otherwise, I assume the build command deletes everything in my output folder and rebuilds the entire site.

Is there a way to get `vuepress build` to either leave that file alone, or copy a CNAME file from my ./src to my ./docs? Should I be looking at the [configureWebpack](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) config to use webpack to do it? (I'm new to webpack.)

Different product completely, but I noticed that [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-config#cname-string) for React has a CNAME config setting that does this for you, so I thought I'd check to see if the VuePress community had something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [relative document](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/assets.html#public-files)

> Sometimes you may need to provide static assets that are not directly referenced in any of your Markdown or theme components - for example, favicons and PWA icons. In such cases, you can put them inside .vuepress/public and they will be copied to the root of the generated directory.

Comment: Thanks so much! Makes perfect sense. Embarrassed that I missed that one and couldn't find it in a search.